Terraform: 'Error: parsing old engine_version: Malformed version: 7.x'
When running terraform apply I got this error:
Error: parsing old engine_version: Malformed version: 7.x
│ 
│   with module.redis_cluster.aws_elasticache_replication_group.replication_group,
│   on ../../../../modules/redis/main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "replication_group":
│   11: resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "replication_group" {
│ 

This appears to be the problem described in hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws#32252, and there's a detailed workaround in a comment:


We had some of the Redis instances configured in Terraform using the wildcard syntax: 6.x
Someone manually updated Redis engines in AWS Console UI to 7.0.*
After the update, the code was updated to 7.x manually. It worked well with the AWS provider 4.37.0.
When I started working in the same repository, I updated the AWS provider from 4.37.0 to 5.9.0 and faced the problem: neither the
7.x value nor 7.0 worked. It was either the Redis versions must match <major>.<minor>... or Error: parsing old engine_version: Malformed version: 7.x error.


The workaround proceeds to describe editing remote state to fix the problem. Is there an easier way to resolve this besides that workaround?

I got this issue after I had used the AWS console to manually upgrade Redis and retrospectively edited my terraform code to match my new Redis configuration.
This is how I fixed the issue:

I downloaded the terraform state (in my case from Terraform Cloud): terraform state pull > temp.tfstate
In a text editor I manually did a search and replace for "engine_version": "6.x", to "engine_version": "7.1",
At the top of the state file you'll find a serial number. This needs incrementing by 1 (otherwise you'll run into a error such as Failed to write state: cannot overwrite existing state with serial 1 with a different state that has the same serial)
I pushed the modified state: terraform state push temp.tfstate

After this, my terraform plan had no errors and showed no differences.

Ran into the same issue during an upgrade of Elasticache from 6.2.6 to 7.1.0 and this was our solution too
